# Write vargarg C preprocessor macro which calls some other macro with each of its arguments and more

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I need to have meta-information about structures in my code. So, I've code some combination of C structures (to store meta information) and C preprocessor macros to initialize these structures without much of boilerplate code. Now it looks like this (really, I'm storing a lot more information about fields, but this code is enough for my question):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct meta_field {
  const char *name;
  size_t offset;
};

struct meta_struct {
  const char *name;
  size_t size;
  struct meta_field fields[];
};

#define META_STRUCT_BEGIN(NAME)               \
  static struct meta_struct s_meta_##NAME = { \
    .name = "" #NAME,                         \
    .size = sizeof(struct NAME),              \
    .fields = {
#define META_STRUCT_END()  ,{NULL, 0}}}
#define META_FIELD(NAME)   { .name = "" #NAME, .offset = offsetof(struct CURRENT_META_STRUCT, NAME) }


struct example {
  int i;
  double d;
};

#define CURRENT_META_STRUCT example
META_STRUCT_BEGIN(CURRENT_META_STRUCT)
  META_FIELD(i),
  META_FIELD(d)
META_STRUCT_END();
#undef CURRENT_META_STRUCT
```

It works. But it has a lot of boilerplate still: `#define CURRENT_META_STRUCT`, usage of `CURRENT_META_STRUCT` as argument to `META_STRUCT_BEGIN()`, `#undef` for `CURRENT_META_STRUCT` — all of this looks ugly, IMHO.

I know, that it is impossible to define macro by macro (so, `META_STRUCT_BEGIN()` can not define `CURRENT_META_STRUCT`). But looking at Branf*ck implementation in C Preprocessor and Boost-PP, I think that it is posisble to implement something which will look like this:

```
META_STRUCT(example,
  META_FIELD(i),
  META_FIELD(d)
)
```

But I can not wrap my head around this preprocessor magic.

Could somebody helps me?

I've read https://github.com/orangeduck/CPP_COMPLETE already, but it didn't help.

Also, it was marked as duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654930/c-variadic-macro-which-expands-into-set-of-macro-calls-on-each-argument), but problem is I need to add "default" argument to all generated macro "calls".

Here are some sketch, what I want to achieve:

```
#define META_FIELD_IMPL(STRUCT, NAME) { .name = "" #NAME, .offset = offsetof(struct STRUCT, NAME) }

#define META_FIELD(NAME)  NAME

#define META_STRUCT(NAME, ... )               \
  static struct meta_struct s_meta_##NAME = { \
    .name = "" #NAME,                         \
    .size = sizeof(struct NAME),              \
    .fields = {                               \
      /* Each ARG from __VA_ARGS__ is META_FIELD(x) and                 \
       * I need to call META_FIELD_IMPL(NAME, <Expansion of META_FIELD>) \
       * for each ARG from _VA_ARGS_ here */                            \
      {NULL, 0}                               \
     }}
```

Now in this example there is only one argument for `META_FIELD()`: `NAME`, but in real system there are 6 arguments for `META_FIELD()` and some helper macro which provide "default" values for common cases, so `META_FIELD()` is necessary and could not be replaced by `NAME` itself.

And one last complication: such `META_STRUCT()` could be called as argument to `META_FIELD()`, because some fields contains pointers to nested meta-structs! Now it is done by declaring named objects for all nested sub-structures, but I want to avoid it too! I understand, that depth of nesting could be limited by some arbitrary constant, it is Ok.

**Update**: I added this example of what I want to type and what I want to get after preprocessor. I can not figure out how to implement all these macros (marked with `/* ??? */`). And, yes, I've checked, manually-coded "end result" compiles fine.

```
enum meta_type { mt_end, mt_int, mt_string, mt_struct };

struct meta_struct;

struct meta_field {
  const char *name;
  enum meta_type type;
  size_t offset;
  struct meta_struct *child;
};

struct meta_struct {
  const char *name;
  size_t size;
  struct meta_field *fields;
};

#define META_STRUCT(NAME, ...)  static struct meta_struct s_meta_##name = { .name = #NAME, .size = sizeof(struct NAME), .fileds = (struct meta_field[]){ /* ??? */, {NULL, mt_end, 0, NULL}}}
#define META_FIELD_IMPL0(STRUCT, NAME, TYPE, CHILD) { .name = #NAME, .type = TYPE, .offset = offsetof(STRUCT, NAME), .child = CHILD }
#define META_FIELD_IMPL1(NAME, TYPE, CHILD)  /* ??? */

#define META_FIELD(NAME, TYPE)       META_FIELD_IMPL1(NAME, TYPE, NULL)
#define META_FIELD_SUB(NAME, CHILD)  META_FIELD_IMPL1(NAME, mt_struct, CHILD)
#define META_SUBSTRUCT(NAME, ...)  (struct meta_struct){ .name = #NAME, .size = sizeof(struct NAME), .fileds = (struct meta_field[]){ /* ??? */, {NULL, mt_end, 0, NULL}}}

/* Example of "input": */
struct child {
  int i;
};

struct parent {
  int i;
  struct child c;
  const char *s;
};

META_STRUCT(parent,
  META_FIELD(i, mt_int),
  META_FIELD_SUB(c, 
    META_SUBSTRUCT(child,
      META_FIELD(i, mt_int)
    )
  ),
  META_FIELD(s, mt_string)
);

/* This should give this */
static struct meta_struct s_meta_parent = {
  .name = "parent",
  .size = sizeof(struct parent),
  .fields = (struct meta_field[]) {
    { .name = "i", .type = mt_int, .offset = offsetof(struct parent, i), .child = NULL },
    { .name = "c", .type = mt_struct, .offset = offsetof(struct parent, c), .child = &(struct meta_struct){
        .name = "child",
        .size = sizeof(struct child),
        .fields = (struct meta_field[]) {
          { .name = "i", .type = mt_int, .offset = offsetof(struct child, i), .child = NULL },
          {NULL, mt_end, 0, NULL}
        }
      }
    },
    { .name = "s", .type = mt_string, .offset = offsetof(struct parent, s), .child = NULL },
    {NULL, mt_end, 0, NULL}
  }
};
```

Comment: Have a look at http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - Variadic macro which expands into set of macro calls on each argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654930/c-variadic-macro-which-expands-into-set-of-macro-calls-on-each-argument)

Comment: Must it look like `META_STRUCT(example, META_FIELD(i), META_FIELD(d))`?  Could it look instead like `META_STRUCT(example, i, d)` or `META_STRUCT(example, (i, d))`?

Comment: @h-walters Here is simplified example, as I mentioned. In reality META_FILED have several arguments (6 of them) and here are helper macros for defaulting some of arguments like `META_FIELD_INT8(name)`, `META_FIELD_STRING()`, etc. It maps badly to simple list of names.

Comment: Certainly nested `META_STRUCT` macros cannot be the same, since they should be expanding to something different?  (I wouldn't expect to see `static struct meta_struct s_meta_##NAME ={` in the middle of an initializer).

Comment: Yes, certainly I need `META_STRUCT()` for top-level (defining static named object) and `META_SUBSTRUCT()` for all nesting levels (defining compound literal), but `META_SUBSTRUCT()`s could be nested for several layers deep! I've updated question again to show whan I want achive with nesting example.

Comment: It'd help if you can sketch out your usage model to the point of the nested `META_SUBSTRUCT`, including what use that field would have when not nesting.  FYI, the solution for this seems to be a non-trivial CPP metaprogram, and this particular detail seems important for a scalable solution.

Comment: @h-walters I've added example of desired input and output to my question. It has only one level of nesting, but it is obvious how to exapnd it to next level.My main problem is to distribute name of struct in question (`parent` and `child` in my example) to all field definitions (`offsetoff()` "calls") without typing name of parent struct in each user-facing `META_FIELD()` macro call.

Comment: @blacklion you are going too far! This requirement could lead to creating your own preprocessor because dealing with nested structure could lead to too many issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach.

### Basic utilities

```
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_I(A,B)
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B
#define COUNT(...) COUNT_I(__VA_ARGS__, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,)
#define COUNT_I(V,_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,X,...) X
```

This is an indirect glue macro (allowing arguments to expand) and a count macro.  The count macro here supports only 9 arguments, but it's easy to expand the pattern.  This just expands to the number of arguments passed.  I'm assuming you've seen this before, but just in case you haven't, this just works by argument shifting; it indirectly expands the arguments, and each extra argument shift above 1 displaces the number list until something is "above" X, which it expands to.

```
#define FIRST(...) FIRST_I(__VA_ARGS__,)
#define FIRST_I(X,...) X
#define REST(X,...) __VA_ARGS__
#define EXPAND(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

...these are operations on tuples.  For the purposes of this answer, a *tuple* is a set of tokens in parentheses.  `FIRST` and `REST` use tuples as data types (should be obvious; `FIRST` indirectly grabs the first element, `REST` expands to everything but that).  `EXPAND` unwraps a tuple.

And the next utility macro:

```
#define FOREACH(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_) GLUE(FOREACH_I_,COUNT TUPLE_)(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_)

#define FOREACH_I_1(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_) MACRO_(DATA_,FIRST TUPLE_)
#define FOREACH_I_2(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_) MACRO_(DATA_,FIRST TUPLE_) FOREACH_I_1(MACRO_,DATA_,(REST TUPLE_))
#define FOREACH_I_3(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_) MACRO_(DATA_,FIRST TUPLE_) FOREACH_I_2(MACRO_,DATA_,(REST TUPLE_))
#define FOREACH_I_4(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_) MACRO_(DATA_,FIRST TUPLE_) FOREACH_I_3(MACRO_,DATA_,(REST TUPLE_))
#define FOREACH_I_5(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_) MACRO_(DATA_,FIRST TUPLE_) FOREACH_I_4(MACRO_,DATA_,(REST TUPLE_))
#define FOREACH_I_6(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_) MACRO_(DATA_,FIRST TUPLE_) FOREACH_I_5(MACRO_,DATA_,(REST TUPLE_))
#define FOREACH_I_7(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_) MACRO_(DATA_,FIRST TUPLE_) FOREACH_I_6(MACRO_,DATA_,(REST TUPLE_))
#define FOREACH_I_8(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_) MACRO_(DATA_,FIRST TUPLE_) FOREACH_I_7(MACRO_,DATA_,(REST TUPLE_))
#define FOREACH_I_9(MACRO_,DATA_,TUPLE_) MACRO_(DATA_,FIRST TUPLE_) FOREACH_I_8(MACRO_,DATA_,(REST TUPLE_))
```

This is the key macro; it is in practice used to apply your structure's type into the lower level macros for each field.  Again, this particular code only works with 9 fields per level, but it should be obvious how to extend this (you probably want to support as many levels as your `COUNT` macro can count to).

The third argument of `FOREACH` should be a tuple; `FOREACH`'s job is to call your macro on `DATA_` and each element of `TUPLE_`.  For example, `FOREACH(FIELD,parent,(i,j,k))` expands to `FIELD(parent,i) FIELD(parent,j) FIELD(parent,k)`.

### Concept for specific utilities

The core calling structure for the specific utilities uses tuple data types; when used with the `FOREACH` macro, underlying calls will curry the outer structure type into each call appropriately.  The calling structure looks like this:

`META_STRUCT(type , FIELD[ , FIELD[ ... ] ] )`

...where each `FIELD` is a 3-tuple:

`(name , type , CHILD )`

...and each `CHILD` is a tuple, which is expanded into a `.child` assignment.  `META_SUBSTRUCT` works similarly.  So according to this call structure, your example will actually wind up being called like this:

`META_STRUCT(parent, (i, mt_int, (NULL)), (c, mt_struct, META_SUBSTRUCT(child,(i,mt_int,(NULL)))),(s, mt_string, (NULL)));`

In practice, `META_SUBSTRUCT` will actually fully expand.  Its expansion will be a "tuple of tokens" that acts as the child assignment; that is, `META_SUBSTRUCT` will expand to the actual assignments in the substruct surrounded by parentheses.  The `FOREACH` macro is applied to this construct, currying the outer structure and the three arguments of the above 3-tuple into the 4-argument macro `APPLY_UTILI_FIELD`.

The *usage* mirrors your usage and adopts to this call structure.  For example, `META_FIELD(i, mt_int)` is just a macro that expands to `(i, mt_int, (NULL))`.

### Specific utilities

```
#define META_STRUCT_BEGIN(NAME_) \
   static struct meta_struct s_meta_##NAME_ = {  \
      .name = #NAME_,  \
      .size = sizeof(struct NAME_),  \
      .fields = (struct meta_field[]) { 

#define META_STRUCT(NAME_,...) \
   META_STRUCT_BEGIN(NAME_) \
      FOREACH(APPLY_META_STRUCT_MACRO,NAME_,(__VA_ARGS__)) \
   META_STRUCT_END()

#define META_STRUCT_END()  \
         {NULL, mt_end, 0, NULL}}}

#define META_SUBSTRUCT(NAME_,...) \
   ( META_SUBSTRUCT_BEGIN(NAME_) \
        FOREACH(APPLY_META_STRUCT_MACRO,NAME_,(__VA_ARGS__)) \
     META_SUBSTRUCT_END() )

#define META_SUBSTRUCT_BEGIN(NAME_) \
   &(struct meta_struct) { \
      .name = #NAME_, \
      .size = sizeof(struct NAME_), \
      .fields = (struct meta_field[]) {

#define META_SUBSTRUCT_END() \
    {NULL, mt_end, 0, NULL}}}

#define APPLY_META_STRUCT_MACRO(DATA_, ARG_) APPLY_UTIL_FIELD(DATA_, EXPAND ARG_)
#define APPLY_UTIL_FIELD(...) APPLY_UTILI_FIELD(__VA_ARGS__)
#define APPLY_UTILI_FIELD( STRUCT_, FIELD_, TYPE_, CHILD_) \
   { .name = #FIELD_, .type = TYPE_, .offset = offsetof(struct STRUCT_, FIELD_), .child = EXPAND CHILD_ },

#define META_FIELD(NAME_, TYPE_) (NAME_, TYPE_, (NULL))
#define META_FIELD_SUB(NAME_, SUB_) (NAME_, mt_struct, SUB_)
```

### Demo

[Showing your example](https://godbolt.org/g/oKYDMm)

### Notes

#### Nesting

These macros allow nesting indefinitely of `META_SUBSTRUCT` calls without running into blue paint, since all such macros wind up being evaluated in the argument substitution phase (`...` argument mentioning `__VA_ARGS__` causes all arguments to expand; each level of `META_SUBSTRUCT` is a top level expansion in this scenario; this condition recurses).

#### Your six fields

Given you're showing an example with less fields than you're using, you need specifically to tweak your user defined `META_FIELD`, `META_FIELD_SUB`, etc macros to produce `k`-tuples instead of 3-tuples (where `k` is what you need).  Then, just adjust `APPLY_UTILI_FIELD`'s arguments and expansion to match.

#### Microsoft Compatibility

This code assumes a standard C preprocessor.  If you're working on MSVC specifically (which doesn't have one), it won't work.  Specifically, MSVC fails to expand `__VA_ARGS__` when it's supposed to; if you *care* to work on MSVC, change the corresponding macros for these three to:

```
#define COUNT(...) EXPAND(COUNT_I(__VA_ARGS__, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,))
#define FIRST(...) EXPAND(FIRST_I(__VA_ARGS__,))
#define APPLY_UTIL_FIELD(...) EXPAND(APPLY_UTILI_FIELD(__VA_ARGS__))
```

The result should also work on standard compliant CPP's.

Comment: Thank you! It works, and I understand how it works, which is very important for me!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `__VA_ARGS__`? Codesnip below accepts maximize 4 fields but you can expands to 5, 6 or more by copy and paste some line of codes (refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654930/c-variadic-macro-which-expands-into-set-of-macro-calls-on-each-argument) for more detail).

Header file:

```
#define META_FIELD1(st,x1) { .name = #x1, .offset = offsetof(struct st, x1) }
#define META_FIELD2(st,x1,x2) META_FIELD1(st,x1), META_FIELD1(st, x2)
#define META_FIELD3(st,x1,x2,x3) META_FIELD1(st,x1), META_FIELD2(st,x2,x3)
#define META_FIELD4(st,x1,x2,x3,x4) META_FIELD1(st,x1), META_FIELD3(st,x2,x3,x4)
#define META_FIELD(st, ...)     META_FIELD4(st, ##__VA_ARGS__) // limit to 4

#define META_STRUCT(st, ...) \
    static struct meta_struct meta_struct_##st = { \
        .name = #st, \
        .size = sizeof(struct st), \
        .fields = { \
            META_FIELD(st, ##__VA_ARGS__) \
        } \
    } \
```

C file:

```
struct sample {
    int i;
    double d;
    const char *test;
    float t;
};

META_STRUCT(sample, i, d, test, t);

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("struct %s { %s, %s, %s, %s } \n", 
            meta_struct_sample.name, 
            meta_struct_sample.fields[0].name, 
            meta_struct_sample.fields[1].name, 
            meta_struct_sample.fields[2].name, 
            meta_struct_sample.fields[3].name);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Output should be: `struct sample { i, i, test, t }`

Comment: First of all,  ##__VA_ARGS__ is gcc extension, as far as I know. It is not portable. And, second, it is simple with only one parameter (name) per field. If you add second one, third one, etc — this simple solution doesn't work anymore or becomes ugly (parameters of fields goes in one list of arguments).